# Selenium write table to CSV file

Tags: python, html, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to get selenium to iterate through the lines in a table element and eventually right these to a CSV. I have tried multiple approaches, some leave me stuck and some just throw errors. Is there a way to nest some sort of for loop within finding the element to iterate through all the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags?

The table I'm using is huge with many nested divs and spans so I'll create a dummy to use

```
<table class="charges">
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>E</td>
<td>F</td>
</tr>

<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

So far I have tried:

```
chargesTableRaw = driver.find_element_by_class_name("charges")

chargesTable = chargesTableRaw.text

print(chargesTable)
```

but this simply gives me the results as

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I have also tried to prettyprint the chargesTable variable and this gives it as one line simply with the linebreaks displayed as rawcode rather than actually dropping a line. Is there a way to iterate through the lines themselves within the table as I believe this will be the only method allowing me to format the data as a CSV

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to Export the Table data into CSV File,

1. First Collect all the Table values, in a manner that each row value is separated by # and Each Column is separated by :
2. Once you got the table values, you can export these in CSV file by using below code,

Column Value example, test1#test2#test3#test4:2#3#4#5:6#2#8#1

```
#import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

    public void creatCSVfiles(String sheetData, String filePath) {
            boolean alreadyPresent = new File(filePath).exists();
            try {
                CsvWriter csvOutputWrite = new CsvWriter(new FileWriterWithEncoding(filePath, CHARSET, true), ',');
                if (alreadyPresent) {
                    //delete file
                }

                //split each row Data separated by : , Get the Number of Rows.

                String[] colHeader = sheetData.split(":");

                for (int count = 0; count < colHeader.length; count++) {

               //Split each row values by # , get the number of columns.
                    String[] colHeadVal = colHeader[count].split("#");

                    for (int rowValue = 0; rowValue < colHeadVal.length; rowValue++) {
                        csvOutputWrite .write(colHeadVal[rowValue]);
                    }

                    csvOutputWrite .endRecord();
                }
                csvOutputWrite .close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //exception message
            }
        }
```

Hope this will solve your Problem.. :)